# Access Archlinux Remotely

Tags: archlinux, remote

So I work at home here in another country and then my employer is in the United States. For me to be able to access their network we use hamachi and I sometimes use their public ip for other links.

Recently, they installed Arch Linux and they want me to configure that machine. I've been sending them instructions but we've been having a lot of trouble with the commands. I'd really like to configure it myself remotely. But we don't even have the desktop gui setup yet and there's no tight vnc for that machine yet.

Just wondering if there's a way I can configure that raspberry pi remotely? Or can we install tightvnc even if there's no desktop gui yet?

Comment: Arch comes with SSH, you may first set up a X session and then install VNC: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vncserver

Comment: i can do this without installing the desktop gui first?

Comment: I can login on one of the computers in the office there but the computers are windows, how can i access it remotely via windows pc?

Answer (score 2):

To do this without a GUI, you need to use SSH. SSH will allow you to manipulate the terminal remotely. To SSH in from outside the machine's network, port 22 TCP needs to be forwarded.

Linux and Mac come with SSH. If your SSH-ing from Windows, download WinSCP or PuTTy.

To SSH from Linux, open a terminal and type:

```
ssh username@[IP]
```

For example:

```
ssh root@172.16.254.1
```

Then you will be prompted to type in the password.

Answer (score 0):

But to get ssh access you need to first generate keys with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "$(whoami)@$(hostname)-$(date -I)"
```

and then move them from id_rsa to ssh_host_rsa_key and id_rsa.pub to ssh_host_rsa_key.pub